# Is it possible to cast object of class to void *?

Tags: c++, stl, qsort

I am trying to use `qsort` from STL to sort array of edge:

```
struct edge
{
    int w,v,weight;
};
```

by weight. What I am trying is:

```
int compare_e(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return ( *(edge *)a->weight - *(edge *)b->weight );
};
```

But I get:

> `const void*' is not a
>   pointer-to-object type

EDIT: 
Ok thx, now my code is compiled but sort seems don't work 100%...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


struct edge
{
    int w,v,weight;
};

struct edge_ID:edge
{
    int id;
};

int compare_e(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return ( ((edge *)a)->weight > ((edge *)b)->weight );
};

int main()
{   
    using namespace std;

    edge *tab = new edge[100];

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        tab[i].weight = rand() % 100;
        cout << i << " => " << tab[i].weight << endl;
    }


    qsort(tab, 100, sizeof(edge), compare_e);

    cout << "AFTER:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " => " << tab[i].weight << endl;
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have some number in wrong place...

Comment: Why not try std::sort much easier

Comment: Is sort works only with Iterators ?

Comment: for an array pointers are iterators

Comment: The comparison function is not yet correct. Returns negative for smaller, 0 for equal, positive for greater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct less_by_weight
{
  bool operator()(const edge& lhs, const edge& rhs) const
  {
    return lhs.weight < rhs.weight;
  }
};

int main()
{   
    const std::size_t size = 100;
    edge *tab = new edge[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        tab[i].weight = rand() % size;
        std::cout << i << " => " << tab[i].weight << '\n';
    }

    std::sort( tab, tab+size, less_by_weight() ); 

    std::cout << "AFTER:" << '\n';
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << " => " << tab[i].weight << '\n';
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: THX it seems to works... but anyway do you have any idea why my code with qsort doesn't work good?

Comment: @MMM: No, and I haven't even looked. Using C++, I haven't used `qsort()` for more than a decade. `std::sort()` is easier to use and faster, too (by design, since the call to the comparator will be inlined), so I see no reason to deal with such code. And you should use `std::vector`, too, instead of doing manual memory management.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it:

```
int compare_e(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return  ((edge *)a)->weight - ((edge *)b)->weight ;
}
```

but if you are writing C++ code, I can't see any reason for doing so - why do you need to use this compare_e function?

Answer (score 3):

You need `((const edge *)a)->weight - ((const edge *)b)->weight`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use qsort, use std::sort: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html

Answer (score 2):

You need an extra parenthesis and should not dereference your pointer with `*`

```
((edge *)a)->weight
```

To answer your addition, your `compare_e` function is now wrong! Keep the first version that substract both weights.

A compare function should return a negative is `A < B`, 0 if `A == B` and a positive if `A > B`. You could implement it using `if/else` but `return A - B` works in most case.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question, it is not possible to cast an object to `void*`. Pointers can be cast to `void*`, but not objects. References may also be cast, but not to `void*`.

`qsort` is not a part of the C++ Standard Template Library, it is a part of the Standard **C** Library, which is quite different.

STL is definitely the way to go with idiomatic C++. @sbi's answer shows you how to use `std::sort` with an array of pointers.